# decode base64 and pass to zip file

Tags: php

```
public function store($location){   
if($this->zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)){
foreach($this->files as $file){
$this->count++;
$this->image_name ="OrderImg".$this->count.".png";
$this->set = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $file);
$this->set = str_replace(' ', '+', $file);
$this->zip->addFile($this->image_name, base64_decode($file));
}
$this->zip->close();
}
}
```

how to i decode my canvas data with base64 and put in to my zip file , i cant make it work here , my intention is to get my canvas data decode with base64 and zip it together.

the zip file didt create and i have no idea why.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the zip file didt create , and i have no idea why.

Comment: Remove the public before the function and check if that works and enable [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/5914775).

Comment: you can use base64_encode() function to encode file as base64. And use $this->zip->addFromString($this->image_name, base64_decode($file)) to add file from string because the file is already a string... Please check this link http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: @Adhan Timothy Younes I tested to use addFromString as well , and still the same. can you make a sample if is alright ?

Comment: where did you get the value of your variable $this->file ? Can you show you full code?

Comment: @Adhan Timothy Younes let me edit the post

Comment: @Adhan Timothy Younes please check again.

Comment: try to encode file like this base64_encode($file)

Comment: public function store($location){

      if($this->zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE | ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)){
        foreach($this->files as $file){
          $this->count++;
          $this->image_name ="OrderImg".$this->count.".png";
          $file_encoded = base64_encode($file);
          $this->zip->addFromString($this->image_name, base64_decode($file_encoded));
        }
 
        $this->zip->close();
      }
 
  }

Comment: @Adhan Timothy Younes Can you post a answer ? i cant see well here. thank you for reply. appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public function store($location){
if($this->zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)){
foreach($this->files as $file){
$this->count++;
$this->image_name ="OrderImg".$this->count.".png";
$file_encoded = base64_encode($file);
$this->zip->addFromString($this->image_name, base64_decode($file_encoded));
}
$this->zip->close();
}
}
```

Even if is not decoded you can also add it to zip as image file like this:

```
$this->zip->addFromString($this->image_name,$file_encoded);
```

Comment: Thank , i got the zip , but the png image was empty , i think i can fix it thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for the party but something like this You can try :

```
public function store($location)
{   
    if($this->zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE))
    {
      foreach($this->files as $file) // assuming you have file **array of base64 encoded images** here
      {
        $this->count++;
        $this->image_name ="OrderImg".$this->count.".png";
        $this->set = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $file);
        $this->set = str_replace(' ', '+', $file);
        $this->zip->addFromString($this->image_name, base64_decode($this->set));// assuming you have base64 encoded string here obtained for $file
      }
        $this->zip->close();
  }
}
```

as you are adding trying to use base64 encoded string you have to use addFromString() rather the addFile()

as for addfile :

```
bool ZipArchive::addFile ( string $filename [, string $localname = NULL [, int $start = 0 [, int $length = 0 ]]] )
```

or simply

```
bool ZipArchive::addFile ( string $file_name_till_fullpath, string $name_you_want_inarchive )
```

and for addFromString :

```
bool ZipArchive::addFromString ( string $localname , string $contents )
```